# Injectivity radius with respect to continuous change of metric

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Suppose $M$ is a smooth manifold and for each $t\in [0,1]$ let $g_t$ be a Riemannian metric on $M$ such that $t\mapsto g_t$ is continuous. If $(M,g_0)$ has positive injectivity radius, does that imply that $(M,g_t)$ has positive injectivity radius for all $g_t$.

I guess a simpler way to say it would be is injectivity radius continuous with respect to a change in metric?

Comment: I don't know the answer off-hand for every type of manifold and every possible topology you could consider putting on the space of metrics.   Could you perhaps be a little more specific?  What topology on metrics do you want to consider, and are you interested in compact manifolds where injectivity radius is very well behaved, or perhaps a more general class?

Answer (score 2):

If $M$ is compact, and $g_t$ is a Riemannian metric, then the injectivity radius is positive. So, we assume that $M$ is not compact. Then let $M_0$ be a bordered hyperbolic surface, with boundary of length $\epsilon,$ and now at time $t$ let the length of the boundary be $\epsilon - t.$ At time $\epsilon$ we will have a cusp (so $0$ injectivity radius).